# rCharts - Manipulating Background Color and Suppressing Axes

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

These are probably separate questions but they both relate to controlling the look of an rCharts/Polycharts plots (to that end, my meta-question is: Where can I find a complete source for all the fields/methods for rCharts/Polycharts?)

My specific questions are:

1) How do I change the background color of the plot? Specifically, I need a color background instead of the default white.

2) How do I suppress the axes (and associated labels and ticks)?

Most of the SO posts with workarounds for the above are for nvd3.

The documentation found here:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rcharts/latest/rcharts.pdf

Was mostly just some basic examples, but nothing covering the above. I did find this thread on github from 2 years ago, noting that complete documentation was on the to-do list.

https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/221

So maybe I'm just not finding it?

Thanks

Comment: I've almost got the second question answered. Assuming my plot is called 'plot1', I can add `plot1$guides(x=list(numticks = 'none', title = ""), y=list(title = "", numticks = 'none'))` and that suppresses all the x and y grid lines but it does leave the word 'undefined' sitting in the top left corner of the plot. Huh.

Comment: Found this SO post regarding the above problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955887/rcharts-not-show-x-axis-elements) but couldn't get his fix to work with my code. Ugh. Should add that there is still a single thick line at the bottom of the graph.

Comment: Perhaps using only the markup for <style> .rChart 
at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/21081469/3811037